# entity.childNodes(0) is not working in mozila

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mozilla

```
function expand(entity) {
    var oImage

    oImage = entity.childNodes(0).all["image"]

    oImage.src = entity.imageOpen

    if (typeof(entity.imageOpen) == "undefined")
        oImage.src = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/MinusSignBlackSilver.gif";

    for(i=0; i < entity.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if(entity.childNodes(i).tagName == "DIV") {
            entity.childNodes(i).style.display = "block"
        }
    }
    entity.open = "true"
}
```

is working fine on IE. But in Mozilla gives error entity.childNodes is not a function.
What is the right syntax to work properly in IE and Mozilla?

Comment: `childNodes` is an Array-like object. Try `entity.childNodes[0]` https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/DOM/element.childNodes

Comment: @Miszy: You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`childNodes` is an Array-like object. Try `entity.childNodes[0]` instead of `(0)`.

Moreover `.all` is IE-specific function and is not a part of the specification. You should replace it with either `querySelectorAll` or other (backward-compatible) function.

**Reference**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/DOM/element.childNodes

Comment: What does *not working* mean? What error do you get in your console?

Comment: after replacing oImage = entity.childNodes[0].all["image"]line by

   var children 
       if (entity.hasChildNodes())

 {children = entity.childNodes;
   for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
   {
   };
 };


oImage = children.all["image"];

But getting error that children.all is not a function

Comment: in place of .all i used querySelectorAll but its not working in mozilla

Comment: It should be working in Firefox since version 16.0: http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector